# way of defining class in a namespace

Tags: c++, qt, class, namespaces

I defined a class in a namespace in a header as follows

```
#ifndef _c1_
#define _c1_

namespace classspace
{
    class Aclass;
}

class Aclass
{
    //body
};

#endif _c1_
```

I added this header to main.cpp and made an object in main() but its returning error that `undefined class 'classspace::Aclass'`
its my main

```
void main()
{
    classspace::Aclass b;
}
```

when I defined class as

```
class classspace::Aclass
{
    //body
};
```

error resolved. 
I saw in Qt mainwindow file using first approach:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

is working without any error. 
what is my mistake in the first approach?

Comment: Can you show the Qt source?

Comment: please see question again I have added it.

Comment: You did not "define" `Aclass` in the header file.  You forward-declared it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class definition must be in the same namespace you declared the class in.

As for the Qt example, the MainWindow declared outside of the namespace *isn't the same class*.

It uses the [Pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). The MainWindow class declared in the namespace is used as a member in the MainWindow class declared outside, and is qualified with its namespace :

```
Ui::MainWindow* ui;
```

The definition of this class is put somewhere else (in a different .cpp file) where it should be in the `Ui` namespace, or with definitions prefixed with the namespace.

Comment: thanks!! even I checked cpp of qt file it was not having namespace but yep it have some auto generated supporting files which defines class into namespace that actually clears my doubt.

Answer (score 6):

```
namespace classspace
{
    class Aclass;
}
```

This declares a class inside a namespace.

```
class Aclass
{
    //body
};
```

This declares and defines a *different* class with the same name in the global namespace

```
class classspace::Aclass
{
    //body
};
```

This defines the class you previously declared in the namespace.

```
void main()
{
    classspace::Aclass b;
}
```

This tries to instantiate the class declared in the namespace. If that class hasn't been defined (only declared), then it is *incomplete* and can't be instantiated.

The Qt example involves two classes: `Ui::MainWindow`, and `MainWindow` in the global namespace. The one in `Ui` has only been declared, so is incomplete in the header. You can do various things with it, such as declare a pointer to it, but you can't instantiate it.

Presumably, there is a separate source file which defines the `Ui` class, instantiates one, and sets the pointer to point at it.

By the way, you shouldn't use [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) for your include guards, or for anything else. Also, the return type of `main` must be `int`.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote? I'd like to correct anything I got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace classspace
{
    class Aclass;
}

class Aclass
{
    //body
};
```

These two classes are two different classes (with same name).

You're using `classspace::Aclass` which has not defined yet. Add the body in the namespce:

```
namespace classspace
{

class Aclass
{
    //body
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the class within the namespace but define it outside the namespace. So the declaration is:

```
classspace::Aclass
```

but the definition defines the implementation for:

```
::Aclass
```

Namespaces should match for declaration and definition.

Comment: Yup - he answered your question, your class is defined outside of the name space its not the same class

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are essentially packages. In your Qt example, the class is forward declared. One way to use namespaces is as follows:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  class MyClass
  {
  };
}
```

If you want to do it like your first example, then you must forward declare it. For example,

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   class MyClass;
}

class MyClass
{
    //body
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine

```
namespace foo
{
  class AClass;
}
namespace goo
{
  class AClass;
}

class AClass
{
}

int main()
{
  AClass myClass;
}
```

Which one are we using? `foo` or `goo`?

You must specify, either by calling all uses of AClass with the namespace name, i.e `foo::AClass`, or by placing all uses of it inside

```
namespace foo
{

}
```