# Defning a namespace class in a header file

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I have a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691749/way-of-defining-class-in-a-namespace) but not the exact.

Assuming we have 2 header files and a main.cpp.
In the first header file we have :

```
  namespace Logic
  {
    class GameManager;
  }
```

In the second header:

```
#include "first_header.h"
class Logic::GameManager 
{
public : 
    void init();
    void run():
};
```

And in the main.cpp i have :

```
#include "first_header.h"
int main()
{
   Logic::GameManager gm;
   gm.init();
   gm.run();
}
```

I get this error until i include the second header in main.cpp :

```
'gm' uses undefined class 'Logic::GameManager'
```

-Is this way of using namespaces and classes correct ?

-Is there a better way to do this?

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

Re-open the namespace to define the class.

```
namespace Logic {

class GameManager 
{
public : 
    void init();
    void run():
};

}
```

And include the second header, not the first, from `main.cpp`. The compiler cannot find the class definition unless it is directly `#include`'d.