# Issues while trying to define a class within a namespace (allocation of incomplete type)

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to create a class in Qt within the Ui namespace.
In my name space I already have 2 classes made with Qt Designer, and using it as reference did not help me solve my problem.

In `myclass.h` I put

```cpp
namespace Ui {class MyClass};

class MyClass : public QObject
{Q_OBJECT
private:
    Ui::MyClass* ui;

//body
}
```

And in `myclass.cpp` I put

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) :QObject(parent),ui (new Ui::MyClass) 
//Here I have : allocation of incomplete type 'Ui::MyClass' 
{
    ui->setupUi(this);       

//Here I have : member access into incomplete type Ui::MyClass'
}
```

I saw [way of defining class in a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691749/way-of-defining-class-in-a-namespace) but I did not find a way to solve my error here.

Comment: `namespace Ui {class MyClass}` won't compile. And even if you add the missing `;` to make that line valid, that is still just a forward declaration. Your class is neither declared nor defined in that namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a Qt issue. It's just C++. To define a class in a namespace, just put the declaration within the namespace:

```
namespace Ui 
{
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    MyClass* ui;

}; // MyClass
} // Ui
```